# Making Firebase and Angular2 project

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase

I'm new at Firebase, I'm starting making a project which has to include Firebase and angular2, but I am such confused about how to implement them. I don't know if a there's the need to have a Back-end implementation (like Java or NodeJs) to handle some security issues (like form validation, authentication, routing etc), or it's enough just implementing Angular2 to handle all these issues. I would be so Thankful about any helpful advice how I could implement these both technologies to build my project successfully. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first firebase is something like your backend firebase can safe get and send request as your backend apps...
and angular js will do the rest like you just said andd all the backend stuff you can handle by firebase :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple explanation on how this 2 works together

Always keep in mind that **Angular** works only in front-end. Its domain is the look and feel, application events, sending data to server and anything else that has something to do with displaying data is coded in this area.

**Backend services** in the other hand interacts with your database, creating business logic, handling authentications, saving / sending of data and other stuff that interacts with the database is coded from here.

Now how these two interact is done by the frontend service to send **HTTP** requests to the **Server which is the backend service**. This is done by using Angulars **$http** service or the so called **jQuery AJAX** or the infamous **XMLHttpRequest JavaScript native**. New technologies today utilizes **Web Sockets** which is being used by **Firebase** and some other frameworks, **Web Sockets** offers a faster way sending / fetching data from server.

The server then interprets the data being sent and send appropriate response. For example getting user list, saving profile, getting reports, logging in, etc.. It would work in this workflow.

1) Angular sends http request to server to get list of users.

2) Backend service installed in the server then interprets the data being sent.

3) Backend service then gets list of users from the database.

4) Backend then sends the data back to the frontend service.

5) Frontend then recieves server response and displays the data to the view.

Also these two is coded separately. To have more detailed explations research about how frontend and backend services interact you can find so much resouces in Google.

Comment: **Preenz**, could you guide me please, what would be the server side that I could use? Maybe Nodejs?

Comment: Firebase is already an option but comes for a price, NodeJS in the other hand is useful too but keep in mind you will create it by hand **from scratch** and takes a bit of learning curve though we have so much in the internet. PHP, Python, Ruby are cheap to free options as well but very high learning curve and they don't utilize web sockets, as of now only Node does that.